401 on wordpress webpage and showing all white
I have a wordpress website that was working fine until this morning. Now, all pages show white.
the funny thing is that if I hover my mouse over the white pages, I can see the links on the back.
When I run inspect, I get the following errors:
`tccl-tti.min.js:1
GET https://scritta.ai/wp-json/wp/v2/settings?_locale=user 401 (Unauthorized)
(anonymous) @ tccl-tti.min.js:1
fetch @ tccl-tti.min.js:1
O @ api-fetch.min.js?ver=4c185334c5ec26e149cc:2
h @ api-fetch.min.js?ver=4c185334c5ec26e149cc:2
(anonymous) @ api-fetch.min.js?ver=4c185334c5ec26e149cc:2
P @ api-fetch.min.js?ver=4c185334c5ec26e149cc:2
(anonymous) @ api-fetch.min.js?ver=4c185334c5ec26e149cc:2
o @ api-fetch.min.js?ver=4c185334c5ec26e149cc:2
(anonymous) @ api-fetch.min.js?ver=4c185334c5ec26e149cc:2
P.method.r @ api-fetch.min.js?ver=4c185334c5ec26e149cc:2
(anonymous) @ api-fetch.min.js?ver=4c185334c5ec26e149cc:2
(anonymous) @ api-fetch.min.js?ver=4c185334c5ec26e149cc:2
o @ api-fetch.min.js?ver=4c185334c5ec26e149cc:2
(anonymous) @ api-fetch.min.js?ver=4c185334c5ec26e149cc:2
(anonymous) @ api-fetch.min.js?ver=4c185334c5ec26e149cc:2
scritta-logo-qlewhgme70wjlt3bqsnd9liivi0lvx91q03g2ag080.png:1 
    
    
   GET https://scritta.ai/wp-content/uploads/2024/03/elementor/thumbs/scritta-logo-qlewhgme70wjlt3bqsnd9liivi0lvx91q03g2ag080.png 404 (Not Found)
api-fetch.min.js?ver=4c185334c5ec26e149cc:2 
    
    
   GET https://scritta.ai/wp-json/wp/v2/users/me?context=edit&_locale=user 401 (Unauthorized)

blog-writing/:1 Uncaught (in promise) {code: 'rest_not_logged_in', message: 'You are not currently logged in.', data: {…}}`

I tried already editing the .htaccess and file and add the following:
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*) RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
The above didn't help
If I change the template, then the website loads fine, but once I switch to the template we use, it doesnt work anymore
Any help is very much appreciated


If I change the template, then the website loads fine, but once I switch to the template we use, it doesnt work anymore

When you say template, do you mean the theme? I.e. if you switch to the Twenty Twenty-Four theme (or any other theme made by WordPress), the website appears as expected?
If so, this means the issue is with the theme. Sometimes, there can be a conflict/error and a function inside a theme can trigger the 401 error. The easiest solution is to obviously switch theme. Or contact the developer of the theme to fix it.
Potentially the conflict is with one of your plugins? Deactivate all plugins, try your original theme again and if its all good, then maybe look for which plugin is causing the issue. But again, this is probably just your theme. Check for an update. Or if an update is what caused this error, look for an older version to roll back to until a fix is available.
